# Why does eliminating from linear equations work but adding them does not?

Tags: linear-algebra

This will be a long post, but bear with me.
If for example, we have two simultaneous linear equations in three unknowns, $2x+3y+3z=7$ and $4x+y+5z=4$, these are the equations of two planes and we can find one of the infinite solutions for this by first setting one of the variables to $0$ then solving simultaneously.

However, if you just add the two equations, you get $6x+4y+8z=11$ which is the equation of a plane and I only know $6x+4y+8z=11$ doesn't correspond to the solution set of the two original simultaneous equations because of my graphical understanding of simultaneous equations in 3 unknowns (i.e. the solutions lie on a line provided the planes arent parallel).

At first, I thought that in adding simultaneous equations, what is happening is that you are taking the information from both of the original equations and combining it, which means the resulting equation must satisfy both of the original equations at the same time, but that's clearly not true.

I am now confused about what is going on when you solve linear equations in general. Even in the simple case of two equations with two unknowns(eg. $2x+3y=4$ and $5x+7y=7$), it seems to me as though eliminating one of the variables doesn't make sense because each of the individual equations has its own infinite solution set, so the $x$ and $y$ variables in each equation aren't really the same. I would be eternally grateful if someone could clear up this confusion about simultaneous linear equations.

Comment: Bare with you? I hardly know you! :) I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the two given equations, you get a new equation which defines a plane.  That plane will contain the line of solutions to your original two equations.  In terms of equations, if you know that $2x + 3y + 3z = 7$ and $4x + y + 5z = 4$, then you know that $6x + 4y + 8z = 11$.  But it does not go the other way around around.  If you know that $6x + 4y + 8z = 11$, then you do not know that $2x + 3y + 3z = 7$ and $4x + y + 5z = 4$.  That is one possibility (one line on the plane), but the plane defined by $6x + 4y + 8z = 11$ contains infinitely many lines parallel to your given line; these other lines correspond to solving $2x + 3y + 3z = c$ and $4x + y + 5z = 11 - c$ for other values of $c$ besides $c = 7$ (your original system of equations).

Comment: What if I add two equations with two unknowns? Does the resulting equation of a line contain the point which is the solution to the original two simulataneous equations?

Comment: @user209531 Yes. One way of thinking about it is that the solution set of the simultaneous equations $E_1,E_2$ is the same as the solution set of the equations $E_1,E_1+E_2$, which is why we can add equations like this.